# reCaptcha error 400

Tags: javascript, web, recaptcha

On a Webpage, when I click on "I'm not robot" checkbox, the Google Recaptcha load infintely and on my JS console I have some error 400 :

[image]

My Key is OK, I use same on an other website and recaptcha work fine, I have this problem only on a specific Website.

Comment: Your domain was typed correct in reCAPTCHA Admin?

Comment: @RafaelDantas yes, when I remove this domain in my reCaptcha Admin I have an explicit error message telling me that my key is incorrect.

Comment: @GildasRossignon Hi! did find out what the problem was?

Comment: @raysn0w for me, the problem was due to I had two recaptcha in same page (One was hidden). I removed one of them and it worked !

Comment: Sometimes this issue is caused by a firewall which replaces the POST request method with the GET. Got one like this just now.

Comment: Have you found solution for this?

Comment: @TusharShukla as mentioned in a previous comment, the problem was due to the fact that i was loading two reCaptcha in the same page (one of them was hidden) i just solved the problem by using one.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I use the wrong Google reCaptcha version. I create v2 in reCaptcha console but used JavaScript of V3 code.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple Captcha plugins installed and uninstalling and removing them fixed the issue for me.